# Printing perl hash keys and values sorted by value

Tags: perl, hash

I have ordered my `hashmap` by `value` and am printing them. After printing the value, I would like to print the corresponding `key`.

My code is currently:

```
foreach my $value (sort (values %student_id_name_hash)){
   print "$value\n";
   // Print correspnding key here
}
```

I am trying to print unique student IDs `(keys)` and corresponding student names `(values)`, which may not be unique.

A method was suggested here that involved `reverse` but depends on the values being unique: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=177969

Is this the best way to go about it? There is no guarantee that the values will be unique in my case.

Comment: Perl uses hashes, not hashmaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the keys as well as values, then you need to iterate based off of the keys and sort based off the value, like so:

```
for my $key ( sort { $student_id_name_hash{$a} cmp $student_id_name_hash{$b} }
    keys %student_id_name_hash )
{
    print "$key - $student_id_name_hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Miller. May I ask what the `$a` and `$b` refer to? I don't understand what is being compared exactly.

Comment: @Giri - Check the perl questions from the last few days -- they have been a popular topic of conversation.

Comment: @Giri Just study [perldoc sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).  It will cover how to use `$a` and `$b` better than any 500 character comment that I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort keys based on values associated with them

```
# standard good practice pragmas
use strict; use warnings; use utf8;

# sample/test data
my %id_hash = (
  X1 => 'Smith, Jane',
  Z9 => 'Doe, John',
);

# sort keys based on value and print
foreach my $key (sort {$id_hash{$a} cmp $id_hash{$b}} keys %id_hash ){
  my $value = $id_hash{$key};
  print "$value\n  $key\n";
}
```